# How to use PIXI.Graphic when using new PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer()

Tags: particles, pixi.js

I'm making particles and want to use the PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer. Based on this demo, http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark it uses a texture for each particle sprite. What I want to use instead of texture is PIXI.Graphics. The particle is not visible/working when using PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer but is visible/working using new PIXI.Container()

```
const renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 800, { transparent: true });
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view)

const stage = new PIXI.Container(); //this works
// const stage = new PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer(); // this. doesn't work


function drawSquare() {
  const spriteParticle = new PIXI.Sprite()

  const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics()
  graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);          
  graphics.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
  spriteParticle.addChild(graphics)
  stage.addChild(spriteParticle)  
}

function loop() {
  renderer.render(stage)
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

drawSquare()
loop()
```

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/lonelydatum/pen/eggEje?editors=0010#0

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @newguy for letting me know about the texture. Here is how to convert the graphics into a texture.

```
let texture = renderer.generateTexture( graphic );
```

Here is a revised codepen:
http://codepen.io/lonelydatum/pen/eggEje?editors=0010#0

```
const renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 800, { transparent: true });
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view)

let stage 

function makeParticleGraphic() {
  const graphic = new PIXI.Graphics()
  graphic.beginFill(0xFF00FF, 1);
  graphic.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
  return graphic
}

function useParticleContainer() {
  stage = new PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer();       
  const graphic = makeParticleGraphic()  
  let texture = renderer.generateTexture( graphic );
  const spriteParticle = new PIXI.Sprite(texture)
  stage.addChild(spriteParticle)  
}

function useContainer() {
  stage = new PIXI.Container()
  const graphic = makeParticleGraphic()
  const spriteParticle = new PIXI.Sprite()
  spriteParticle.addChild(graphic)
  stage.addChild(spriteParticle)  
}

function loop() {
  renderer.render(stage)
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

useParticleContainer()
// useContainer()
loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using canvas or webGL. In Canvas, when you use `PIXI.Container` to hold `PIXI.Graphics`, it will loop through all its Graphics object children and call `CanvasGraphicsRenderer` to render it. What it does is like drawing a shape using Canvas API. However in ParticlesContainer, it will use every child's baseTexture to drawImage onto the canvas. This means in `ParticleContainer` you need to give its children a shared `BaseTexture` which is not supplied in your code.

Comment: Thanks @newguy. Do you mind applying your solution to my codepen: http://codepen.io/lonelydatum/pen/qqoVYW?editors=0110 and sharing your code. Thanks!

Comment: @Lonelydatum You don't use `ParticleContainer` directly as stage. Stage needs to be a `PIXI.Container`. Then you add a `ParticleContainer` object onto the stage.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. It seems to work when using the ParticleContainer directly as the stage though. What are the negative points in doing so? Just curious.